# Create an array of repeated numbers based on percentage

Tags: r

I have an array containing information of percent of each number.
e.g. -

```
percent_number = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1)
```

I have to create an array 'numbers' of size N (e.g. N = 10) which contains repeated numbers based on 'percent_number'.
i.e. expected output:

```
numbers = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4)
```

Can we create this array using a one line code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
rep(seq_along(percent_number), percent_number * 10)

 [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4
```